# Else statement in Javascript for Event listener not working

Tags: javascript, html

The below code should log 'success' onto the console when I fill the html field but it doesn't. Any help would be nice.

Javascript code:

```
let taskInput = document.querySelector('.input').value;
let myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');
let msgArea = document.querySelector('.msg');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', onsubmit);

function onsubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(taskInput=='') {
    msgArea.classList.add('alert')
    msgArea.classList.add('alert-danger');
    msgArea.style.backgroundColor = '#ec4646';
    msgArea.innerHTML = 'Alert! Fill the fields first';
    }
    else { 
    console.log('success'); //this is not logging onto the console
    }
}
```

Comment: The value of `taskInput` is set only once at the beginning of your program. It does not refresh when you input something nor when you submit the form.

Comment: @Teemu Just tried but then it doesn't show the error it is supposed to show

Comment: @deceze Yeah you are right. But then how can I resolve it

Comment: Read `document.querySelector('.input').value` every time you need its *current* value…

Comment: @deceze thanks man! Now it works exactly how I want it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// STEP 1: Instead of:
let taskInput = document.querySelector('.input').value;
// Use:
let taskInput = document.querySelector('.input');

// STEP 2: Instead of:
// ...
 if (taskInput == '') {
// ...
// Use:
 if (taskInput.value.trim() === '') {
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here: `let taskInput = document.querySelector('.input').value;`

```js
const taskInput = document.querySelector('.input')
let inputVal = taskInput.value

taskInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
  inputVal = e.target.value
})

// Don't forget to update the if statement
function onsubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (inputVal === '') {
    /* your code */
  } else {
    console.log('success')
  }
}
```